# Google app engine not sending mail despite calls appearing in Quota details

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have spent the weekend playing with Google App Engine and Google Web Toolkit and have got along pretty well and built a simple app.

The stumbling block seems to be sending e-mails. My code is:

```
private void sendOffenderMail( OffenceDetails offence )
{
    if( offence.email == null || offence.email.equals("") )
    {
        return;
    }

    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    String msgBody = "You have been added to the list";

    if( offence.notes != null && !offence.notes.equals( "" ) )
    {
        msgBody += "\n\nThe following notes were included:\n\n" + offence.notes;
    }

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {

        msg.setFrom( new InternetAddress(<gmail account belonging to project viewer>, "List Admin") );
        msg.addRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress (offence.email, offence.name )
                );
        msg.setSubject("You've been added to the list...");
        msg.setText(msgBody);
        Transport.send(msg);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run this on the development server logs get printed out in the console about the mail that would have been sent.
When I deploy to app engine and try there nothing happens, I don't get any mail.

If I look in to the quota details I can see mail api calls there. If I look at the logs there are no errors (but I can't see and of my logs in there...).

It seems odd that I have essentially been charged for sending this (quota used up) but no mails actually got through.

I HAVE checked my spam folder BTW.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that gmail account that you use is a Project Viewer. The [docs state](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Sending_Mail) that it should be a Developer.

Comment: I tried changing the owner of the account to a developer (despite not actually finding that bit in the docs, it just said an admin which I believe a viewer is) but the email was still not sent.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just used the e-mail address of the currently logged in user - which is always an admin as you can only get to this part of the app if you're an admin.
I could not get it to work using a hardwired address belonging to one of the admins.